# How can I return FlightOfferSearch and FlightOrder objects as JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, amadeus

If I try to return FlightOfferSearch[] or FlightOrder objects from a handler method of my Spring Boot REST Controller, they don't seem to get serialized correctly like simpler POJOs I've worked with before where Jackson handled JSON serialization.

My code (actual API calls mostly identical to [the SDK github example](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java/blob/master/src/examples/flight/createorders/FlightCreateOrders.java)):

```
import com.amadeus.Amadeus;
import com.amadeus.Params;
import com.amadeus.exceptions.ResponseException;
import com.amadeus.resources.FlightOfferSearch;
import com.amadeus.resources.FlightOrder;
import com.amadeus.resources.Traveler;
import io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Objects;

@RequestMapping("api/v1")
@RestController
public class TestController {

  private static Amadeus getFreshAccessToken() {
    Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.load();
    return Amadeus
        .builder(Objects.requireNonNull(dotenv.get("AMADEUS_KEY")), Objects.requireNonNull(dotenv.get("AMADEUS_SECRET")))
        .build();
  }

  @GetMapping("/test")
  FlightOrder testHandler() throws ResponseException {
    Amadeus amadeus = getFreshAccessToken();

    Traveler traveler = new Traveler();

    traveler.setId("1");
    traveler.setDateOfBirth("2000-04-14");
    traveler.setName(traveler.new Name("JORGE", "GONZALES"));

    Traveler.Phone[] phone = new Traveler.Phone[1];
    phone[0] = traveler.new Phone();
    phone[0].setCountryCallingCode("33");
    phone[0].setNumber("675426222");
    phone[0].setDeviceType("MOBILE");

    Traveler.Contact contact = traveler.new Contact();
    contact.setPhones(phone);
    traveler.setContact(contact);

    Traveler.Document[] document = new Traveler.Document[1];
    document[0] = traveler.new Document();
    document[0].setDocumentType("PASSPORT");
    document[0].setNumber("480080076");
    document[0].setExpiryDate("2022-10-11");
    document[0].setIssuanceCountry("ES");
    document[0].setNationality("ES");
    document[0].setHolder(true);
    traveler.setDocuments(document);

    Traveler[] travelerArray = new Traveler[1];
    travelerArray[0] = traveler;
    System.out.println(travelerArray[0]);

    FlightOfferSearch[] flightOffersSearches = amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.get(
        Params.with("originLocationCode", "SYD")
                .and("destinationLocationCode", "BKK")
                .and("departureDate", "2020-11-01")
                .and("returnDate", "2020-11-08")
                .and("adults", 1)
                .and("max", 1));

    FlightOrder order = amadeus.booking.flightOrders.post(flightOffersSearches, travelerArray);

    return order;
  }

}
```

Postman requests return:

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "JSON mapping problem: com.amadeus.resources.FlightOrder[\"response\"]->com.amadeus.Response[\"result\"]->com.google.gson.JsonObject[\"asBoolean\"]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.amadeus.resources.FlightOrder[\"response\"]->com.amadeus.Response[\"result\"]->com.google.gson.JsonObject[\"asBoolean\"])",
```

and the server logs

```
ERROR 45864 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: JSON mapping problem: com.amadeus.resources.FlightOrder["response"]->com.amadeus.Response["result"]->com.google.gson.JsonObject["asBoolean"]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.amadeus.resources.FlightOrder["response"]->com.amadeus.Response["result"]->com.google.gson.JsonObject["asBoolean"])] with root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsBoolean(JsonElement.java:153) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1433) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:921) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:294) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]
```

Is there something else I need to do to convert them to JSON format?

Comment: getAsBoolean() throws. You can check for the booleans values are correct and may have null values.

Comment: At the moment you tried to use the flight create order it wasn't released yet. It has been released yesterday version 4.0.0. Can you try again?

Comment: I tried with amadeus-java 4.0.0 and am still getting the same error, only with lines 3-6 from the Exception missing (at sun.reflect.[...] up to line at java.lang.reflect.[...]) from the server log output. A temporary workaround I found is to make an explicit conversion by returning ResponseEntity<Object>(objectMapper.readValue(order.getResponse().getBody(), Object.class), HttpStatus.OK).
edit: I also got the same error when trying to return FlightOfferSearch objects, so I don't think it's something FlightOrder-specific in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked the Java SDK helpers to fix and add a couple of things:

- Fix a bug that was trying to book all the flights of the search.
- Added a new method allowing you to book using a single FlightOfferSearch (not an array)
- I added a method to book from a FlightPrice object. In theory, you shouldn't book from a FlightOfferSearch directly, you should call the Flight Offers Price API to confirm the price and availability before booking. You can find an example [here](https://eur01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Famadeus4dev%2Famadeus-java%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fsrc%2Fexamples%2Fflight%2Fcreateorders%2FFlightCreateOrders.java&data=02%7C01%7C%7C2378b49652604dc2a88908d7e12f7654%7Cb3f4f7c272ce4192aba4d6c7719b5766%7C0%7C0%7C637225466281786327&sdata=0USDJmIWVXRDlg6aRYc77JPnZarkDq3KojBqVDbxqxE%3D&reserved=0). You can learn more about the flight booking flow in [this tutorial](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/tutorial-booking-engine-amadeus-flight-booking-api).

For your information, all our APIs support the post with a JSON direclty (in String or in JsonObject) if any of our helpers fail you can use that method (take your object, deserialize it in String/JSON and use it directly).

I released a new version of the SDK version `4.1.0` please update to this version.