# How do I parse a JSON request into a FlightOfferSearch[] object?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, amadeus

I have trouble deserializing the Response Example JSON for a `FlightOfferSearch` from [here](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) when passing it to my test REST controller:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @PostMapping("/search")
  String searchHandler(@RequestBody FlightOfferSearch[] flightOfferSearches) {
    return flightOfferSearches[0].toString();
  }
}
```

(minimal example with just Spring Boot Starter App with "Web" dependency and `gson 2.8.5` and `amadeus-java 4.1.0` added in the pom.xml)

I'm getting this in IntelliJ:

```
2020-04-20 17:05:59.392  WARN 47240 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Conflicting setter definitions for property "fixedLengthStreamingMode": java.net.HttpURLConnection#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(1 params) vs java.net.HttpURLConnection#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(1 params); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "fixedLengthStreamingMode": java.net.HttpURLConnection#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(1 params) vs java.net.HttpURLConnection#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(1 params)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]

Process finished with exit code -1
```

and this in Postman:

```
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "JSON parse error: Conflicting setter definitions for property \"fixedLengthStreamingMode\": java.net.HttpURLConnection#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(1 params) vs java.net.HttpURLConnection#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(1 params); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property \"fixedLengthStreamingMode\": java.net.HttpURLConnection#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(1 params) vs java.net.HttpURLConnection#setFixedLengthStreamingMode(1 params)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"
```

All comments are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Show this class FlightOfferSearch

Comment: It's this class: https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amadeus/resources/FlightOfferSearch.java

Comment: It seems the class only declares getters. Does that mean I should create a custom subclass if I want to use Jackson to convert it to and from JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't create setters for some of the fields for your parameter class, but the problem lies deeper - your way of handling this, is incorrect. 
Spring's `@RestController` converts incoming payload from JSON to the object parameter of the controller method by default and converts return object to JSON.

You don't need to include any extra dependencies apart `spring-boot-starter-web`, which includes a default Jackson JSON mapper.

But even if you do use `gson` instead, Spring still will work this exact way only it'll use `gson` instead.

Everything you need to do is to create a class, which represents your incoming json correctly and use that class as a parameter, it has to have an empty constructor, setters if you use this object as a request body and getters if you use that object as a response body.

**UPD:**
If you don't own the object you are using as a controller method's parameter - I recommend creating custom POJO anyway, using non-incapsulated third-party library considered a smell at least, it violates the encapsulation and creates tight coupling to the third-party library.

Comment: It's not my own POJO but a class from the [amadeus-java SDK](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java). That is where the two dependencies come from.

Comment: Here, I'm only trying to parse from JSON into an object. When trying to the opposite I had a different problem which I asked about a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815078/how-can-i-return-flightoffersearch-and-flightorder-objects-as-json?noredirect=1#comment107654631_60815078). I'm not sure if it's related to this problem, though, since the error message is different.

Comment: Why do you use SDK's class instead of custom POJO?

Comment: The SDK has wrapper methods that return FlightOfferSearch objects and I have to use the same object as parameters to make requests when I want to use the SDK's methods. But I want to do some logic in an external app which is why I want to be able to (de)serialize them.

Comment: Why don't you just use custom pojo and convert it to FlightOfferSearch on demand for the library encapsulated component to do the job and vice versa?

Comment: Sorry I never received a notification for your reply on the other thread. I reply directly [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815078/how-can-i-return-flightoffersearch-and-flightorder-objects-as-json?noredirect=1#comment107654631_60815078). If you want an example on how to convert a JSON into an object using Gson you can take a look at [this class](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amadeus/booking/FlightOrders.java) method  buildFlightOffersJSON